# SVG Triangle To Circle Animation

Tags: svg, css-animations

I am currently trying to create an animation where a triangle morphs into a circle and back again. My current problem is that when they morph into each other, the lines curve in different ways.

[image]
*Transition between circle and triangle*

In this image you can see that the top left side curves outwards, whiles the bottom left side curves inwards. I am trying to make it so the transition is symmetrical.

I have tried changing the control points to adjust how the curve functions but I cannot make the transition look symmetrical.

Somewhat new to this, so please excuse my terminology but if anyone could help, I would appreciate it a lot.

Here is my current code:

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path transform="scale(0.5)" transform-origin="center" style="transform-box: fill-box;">
    <animate 
       attributeName="d" 
       dur="3000ms" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       values="M 0,0 C 100,50 100,50 100,50 0,100 0,100 0,100
               0,50 0,50 0,50 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z;
                     
               M 50,0 C 77.5,0 100,22.5 100,50 100,77.5 77.5,100 50,100 22.5,100 0,77.5
               0,50 0,22.5 22.5,0 50,0 Z;
                     
               M 0,0 C 100,50 100,50 100,50 0,100 0,100 0,100
               0,50 0,50 0,50 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z;"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close.
For a more symmetric morphing animation just "pull" the 2 cubic bézier control points to the starting and end coordinates separately:

##### Triangular path

```
M 0 0 
C 0 0     100 50  100 50 
C 100 50  0 100   0 100 
C 0 100   0 50    0 50 
C 0 50    0 0     0 0 
Z
```

As you can see

1. cubic control point coordinates equal the previous commands on-path point
2. control point coincides with the segment's final point

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path transform="scale(0.5)" transform-origin="center" style="transform-box: fill-box;">
    <animate 
       attributeName="d" 
       dur="3000ms" 
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       values="M 0 0 C 0 0 100 50 100 50 C 100 50 0 100 0 100 C 0 100 0 50 0 50 C 0 50 0 0 0 0 Z;
                     
               M 50,0 C 77.5,0 100,22.5 100,50 100,77.5 77.5,100 50,100 22.5,100 0,77.5
               0,50 0,22.5 22.5,0 50,0 Z;
                     
               M 0 0 C 0 0 100 50 100 50 C 100 50 0 100 0 100 C 0 100 0 50 0 50 C 0 50 0 0 0 0 Z;"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that’s exactly what I wanted